# unable to access outside xml config file in spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

am trying to use an xml file from outside jar.now its getting null pointer exception

```
 private static String getRequestConfigurationLocation() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        URL resourceURL = ConfigurationFactory.class.getResource(Configuration.XML_CONF);
        //Assert.notNull(resourceURL, "Resource url is null : ");
        String urlFilePath = resourceURL.getFile();
        String actualFilePath = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(urlFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return actualFilePath;
    }
```

Configuration

```
public class ConfigurationFactory
{

    public static final String XML_CONF = "D:/DEV//X/X1/Service/target/conf/rConfiguration.xml";
}
```

how can i use external file in an executable jar

error log

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use java.util.Properties to access external file,
refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540617/12083015) answer to load xml properties file

Answer (score 0):

In your property file try :

external.config=D:/DEV//X/X1/Service/target/conf/rConfiguration.xml

Or
annotate your configuration file with following

@configuration
@ImportResource("D:/DEV//X/X1/Service/target/conf/rConfiguration.xml")

Comment: how to inject @import resource into " XML_CONF"

Comment: Try this : https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-importresource-annotation-example.html