# How to load properties on util class

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I defined my properties file location on XML, and register my custom util class as bean. (with factory-method is “getInstance”)

What I want is I want to load my properties value before my Custom util construction us called.

```
class AUtil
{
   private static AUtil instance;

   @Value("something")
   private m;

   private AUtil() {}

   public static AUtil() {
       if (instance == null) instance = new AUtil();

       return instance;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is that static in front of a constructor? and why can't you write an argument constructor in this class and change the xml config for bean to pass the required value?

Comment: You should not access the properties directly in Utils classes. You should pass the values as method arguments

Comment: As suggested in the comments you should pass that prop values in method arguments. But still, if you want to do then you have to write code to load properties manually. Spring will not inject them automatically.

Comment: @Saurabh Is there any reference or example code for me?

Comment: @Chloe you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8540617/12013107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use @PostConstruct as:
when the constructor is called, the bean is not yet initialized - i.e. no dependencies are injected. In the @PostConstruct method the bean is fully initialized and you can use the dependencies.